# Как узнать включена ли геолокация?

Tags: android

Нужно узнать включена ли геолокация на устройстве и получить оповещение если ее включили/выключили? Наверно как-то через бродкасты, но не могу найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для контроля изменения состояния геолокации нужно настроить ресивер на `android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED`, ну а собственно для определения состояния:

`LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
 boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`